# add_post_meta not saved

Tags: metabox, database, front-end, post-meta

EDIT 
I changed it to

```
            if(isset($_POST['Make']))
    update_post_meta($pid,"Make", $_POST['Make']);

if(isset($_POST['Year']))
    update_post_meta($pid,"Year", $_POST['Year']);

if(isset($_POST['Model']))
    update_post_meta($pid,"Model", $_POST['Model']);

if(isset($_POST['Trim']))
    update_post_meta($pid,"Trim", $_POST['Trim']);
```

And now it is working intermittently

END EDIT

I am updating meta boxes I created. They function flawlessly on the back-end. But on the front end I am having limited success. Firebug says the `POST` request has the values in them but they are not ending up in the database.

Can anyone tell me why?

```
add_post_meta($pid, 'Year', $_POST['Year'], true);
```

is posting the meta key but not the meta value of a select box?

More information available if you need just let me know what it is.

EDIT TO PROVIDE MORE CODE 
This a condensed version of the form

```
    <form method="post" <?php echo $enc; ?>  action="<?php 
     echo post_new_with_pid_stuff_thg($pid,  
     $new_auction_step);?>" > 
     <ul class="post-new">
     <li>

    <?php do_action('cn_before_image_upload');

if(isset($_POST['Make']))
update_post_meta($pid, 'Make', $_POST['Make'], true);

if(isset($_POST['Year']))
            update_post_meta($pid, 'Year', $_POST['Year'], true);


if(isset($_POST['Model']))
    update_post_meta($pid, 'Model', $_POST['Model'], true);

if(isset($_POST['Trim']))
    update_post_meta($pid, 'Trim', $_POST['Trim'], true);
 ?>
  </li>
```

This is the before_image_upload in functions.php

```
        add_action('cn_before_image_upload', 'custom_nate_car');

       function custom_nate_car(){

      include_once 'select.php';
     global $wpdb;
     ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#Trim").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#Model").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#Make").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#Year").change(function(){
        $("select#Make").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#Make").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id = $("select#Year option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/select_type.php", {id:id},  
        function(data){
            $("select#Make").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#Make").html(data);

        });
        });
       $('select#Make').change(function() {
       $("select#Model").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#Model").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id2 = $("select#Make option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/select_model.php", {id2:id2}, 
        function(data2){
            $("select#Model").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#Model").html(data2);
       });

        $('select#Model').change(function() {
       $("select#Trim").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#Trim").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id3 = $("select#Model option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/select_trim.php", {id3:id3}, 
        function(data3){
            $("select#Trim").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#Trim").html(data3);
       });
       $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
        var year = $("select#Year option:selected").attr('value');
        var make = $("select#Make option:selected").attr('value');
        if(year>0 && make>0)
        {
            var result = $("select#Make option:selected").html();
            $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
        }
        return false;
    });

});
       });
      });
     </script>

    <h2>Car YEAR/MAKE/MODEL/TRIM:</h2><br />
    <select name="Year" class="do_input" size="20" id="Year">
        <?php echo $opt->getYear(); ?>
    </select>
    <select name="Make" class="do_input" size="20"  id="Make">
      <option>Choose...</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Model" class="do_input" size="20" id="Model">

    </select>
    <select name="Trim" class="do_input" size="20" id="Trim">

    </select>
    <br /><br />
```

the select.php that the jquery calls is formatted like this

```
class selectList {

public function getModel(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results(
        "

        SELECT DISTINCT model, make

        FROM wp_car_details 

        WHERE make = '$_POST[id2]'

        ORDER BY model ASC

        "
        );

    foreach ($sql as $res) {
    echo '<option value="'.$res->model.'">'.$res->model.'</option>';
    }
    die();
}
```

one public function for each of the select boxes. is there a problem with my loop?

EDIT 
Did 
      var_dump($_POST);

Looks like the select values are not going in into the $_POST array but showing fine in firebug.

Comment: Can you add more code? Also I think that you'll use `update_post_meta` in place of `add_post_meta`. See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) for better knowledge.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. If you need to add more info, do it as an edit in your **original** post. Thank you

Comment: This is an exact duplicate (double post) of [Custom Meta Boxes Not Updating From Front End](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157215/custom-meta-boxes-not-updating-from-front-end)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate.. It didn't feel like I was doing that when I posted this... Problem corrected